# Why is there an error message if the variable is encased in double quotes?

Tags: php

Look at the code below

```
<?php
//The array is storing a blog entry in it
$entry = array ('title' => 'sample title',
        'date' => 'August 9, 2011',
        'author' => 'daNullSet',
        'body' => 'I shall become a web developer IA',);
echo "The title of the blog is ".$entry['title']."<br />";
?>
```

The code above executes quite well, but it returns the following parse error when I enclose $entry['title'] in double quotes while concatenating with other strings in echo statement.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-ex\test.php on line 7

Can you guide about the reason of the error? I am absolutely new to programming. Thank you

Comment: please remove the `","` after **'I shall become a web developer IA'**

Comment: echo 'The title of the blog is "'.$entry['title'].'"<br />';

Comment: @Jalpesh the extra comma is optional, and I _always_ include it in PHP. So it's a matter of taste. OP: Don't just include the coede that works well, include the code that actually throws the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a value from an associative array in a string, you need to use the ["complex (curly) syntax"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex). What this means, in effect, is that you need to wrap it in `{}`, like this:

```
echo "The title of the blog is {$entry['title']}<br />";
```

If you try and use a "complex" variable directly in a double-quoted string without using the braces, you will get the parse error you report.

It would be well worth your reading [this entire page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) thoroughly so you know what is and isn't allowed.

Comment: i think he wants wrap the title in "quotes"

Comment: @Dagon I know it is a little unclear - but this answer is based on the syntax error he reported, and as far as I am aware that is the only way to provoke that particular error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//The array is storing a blog entry in it
$entry = array ('title' => 'sample title',
        'date' => 'August 9, 2011',
        'author' => 'daNullSet',
        'body' => 'I shall become a web developer IA');
echo "The title of the blog is '".$entry['title']."'<br />";
?>
```

Please try this

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I know the reson why that cause error is because the compiler always checks for start and end syntax like {}, (), "", ''. When you start a syntax, you should give it an end mark. And if I understand your question correctly, your problem is you want to add " into "". You can use \" to escape the compiler to read it as a syntax.

```
echo "The title of the blog is \"".$entry['title']."\"<br/>";
```